# Splitting out the output of ps using Python

Tags: python, regex, linux

On Linux, the command ps aux outputs a list of processes with multiple columns for each stat. e.g.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
postfix  22611  0.0  0.2  54136  2544 ?        S    15:26   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
apache   22920  0.0  1.5 198340 16588 ?        S    09:58   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

I want to be able to read this in using Python and split out each row and then each column so they can be used as values.

For the most part, this is not a problem:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
processes = ps.split('\n')
```

I can now loop through processes to get each row and split it out by spaces, for example

```
sep = re.compile('[\s]+')
for row in processes:
    print sep.split(row)
```

However, the problem is that the last column, the command, sometimes has spaces in. In the example above this can be seen in command

```
pickup -l -t fifo -u
```

which would be split out as

```
['postfix', '22611', '0.0', '0.2', '54136', '2544', '?', 'S', '15:26', '0:00', 'pickup', '-l', '-t', 'fifo', '-u']
```

but I really want it as:

```
['postfix', '22611', '0.0', '0.2', '54136', '2544', '?', 'S', '15:26', '0:00', 'pickup -l -t fifo -u']
```

So my question is, how can I split out the columns but when it comes to the command column, keep the whole string as one list element rather than split out by spaces?

Comment: Don't do that. ps output is **NOT** intended to be machine-readable. Either dig this information on the /proc filesystem, or use PSI, like suggested by vartec.

Comment: Why is it not supposed to be machine-readable?

Comment: David, I think Juliano simply means to say that the PS output varies so much (as you pointed out, the command string is split into lots of pieces by your regex and there is no way for the program to know this undesirable) that it would be easier for you to use the /proc fs or PSI.  Its not that it is *NOT MACHINE READABLE* it is that it will be a pain to do.

Comment: Try using `psutil` instead - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390799/992887

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the second parameter to `split` which specifies the maximum number of fields to split the string into. I guess you can find the number by counting the number of fields in the first line, i.e. the column titles.

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
processes = ps.split('\n')
# this specifies the number of splits, so the splitted lines
# will have (nfields+1) elements
nfields = len(processes[0].split()) - 1
for row in processes[1:]:
    print row.split(None, nfields)
```

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [python.psutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/) package.

`psutil.process_iter` returns a generator which you can use to iterate over all processes.
`p.cmdline` is a list of each Process object's cmdline arguments, separated just the way you want.

You can create a dictionary of pids vs `(pid,cmdline,path)` with just one line and then use it anyway you want.

```
pid_dict = dict([(p.pid, dict([('pid',p.pid), ('cmdline',p.cmdline), ('path',p.path)]))
                 for p in psutil.process_iter()]))
```

Comment: +1, psutil is definitely the way to go (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/). It's portable and doesn't rely on output of ps.

Comment: The example provided could be improved by simplifying the use case. I found it very valuable to learn that the `Process` objects that `next(process_iter())` returns has an `as_dict` method a (IMO) much more useful object than the dict this answer creates for you. Additionally, note that not all `Process` values are strings!

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [PSI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PSI/) instead? PSI provides process information on Linux and other Unix variants.

```
import psi.process
for p in psi.process.ProcessTable().values(): …
```

Comment: This was much easier than trying to parse the output of ps.

Comment: FWIW, the link to PSI is dead as of 2014-09-19

Answer (score 1):

The `maxsplit` optional argument to the `split` method might help you:

```
sep.split.(row, maxsplit=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice routine and usage to get you going:

```
def getProcessData():
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    processes = ps.split('\n')
    # this specifies the number of splits, so the splitted lines
    # will have (nfields+1) elements
    nfields = len(processes[0].split()) - 1
    retval = []
    for row in processes[1:]:
        retval.append(row.split(None, nfields))
    return retval

wantpid = int(contents[0])
pstats = getProcessData()
for ps in pstats:
    if (not len(ps) >= 1): continue
    if (int(ps[1]) == wantpid):
        print "process data:"
        print "USER              PID       %CPU        %MEM       VSZ        RSS        TTY       STAT      START TIME      COMMAND"
        print "%-10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s %10.10s  %s" % (ps[0], ps[1], ps[2], ps[3], ps[4], ps[5], ps[6], ps[7], ps[8], ps[9])
```