# Process list on Linux via Python

Tags: python, linux

How can I get running process list using Python on Linux?

Answer (score 131):

IMO looking at the `/proc` filesystem is less nasty than hacking the text output of `ps`.

```
import os
pids = [pid for pid in os.listdir('/proc') if pid.isdigit()]

for pid in pids:
    try:
        print open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'rb').read().split('\0')
    except IOError: # proc has already terminated
        continue
```

Comment: You will have to surround the read() call with a try/except block as a pid returned from reading os.listdir('/proc') may no longer exist by the time you read the cmdline.

Comment: At last! Validation! Now I can stop! :-)

Comment: -1 for /proc since its not portable and there are better interfaces available

Comment: Watch out: the command line is terminated by 0x00.
Whitespaces are also replaced with the same character.

Comment: Just use `psutil` - it does all this through a nice Pythonic interface and is portable if you ever want to run on a non-Linux server.

Comment: Everything in Linux is a file. I think reading from proc is the best way.

Comment: You forgot about close()!

Comment: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc'

Comment: I think it's the best answer for this question. And "portability" is not needed - question about linux only

Comment: For fun, a oneliner that seems to work in python3.5 and up. I'll let you know when it fails: `pidmap = {p.parent.name: b' '.join(p.read_bytes().strip(b'\0').split(b'\0')).decode('ascii') for p in pathlib.Path('/proc').glob('*/cmdline')}`

Comment: @PADYMKO: Or rather, forgot about `with`.

Answer (score 90):

You could use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a platform independent solution!

```
import psutil
psutil.pids()

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 46, 48, 50, 51, 178, 182, 222, 223, 224,
268, 1215, 1216, 1220, 1221, 1243, 1244, 1301, 1601, 2237, 2355,
2637, 2774, 3932, 4176, 4177, 4185, 4187, 4189, 4225, 4243, 4245, 
4263, 4282, 4306, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4337, 4339, 4357, 4358, 
4363, 4383, 4395, 4408, 4433, 4443, 4445, 4446, 5167, 5234, 5235, 
5252, 5318, 5424, 5644, 6987, 7054, 7055, 7071]
```

Comment: just take a look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation).

Comment: It's not completely platform independent -- on OSX you can run into AccessDenied errors:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/psutil/bsjpawhiWms

Comment: @amos kinda makes sense - you'd want to have privileges in place first before reaching out to information about processes. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: To amplify the OSX point - you need root privileges on OSX to get process info, unlike Linux.

Comment: And it is available as python-psutil from epel for fedora/centos/rhel family.

Comment: in py3, use `get_pid_list()` instead `pids()`

Comment: I've had trouble with this: I start a dummy process, then look through all the processes for one with the name `dummy_process` and I can't see it. If I call `ps -u` then I can see my process. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @enthus1ast your link seems down, new docs seem to be here: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 8):

The sanctioned way of creating and using child processes is through the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
pl = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-U', '0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print pl
```

The command is broken down into a python list of arguments so that it does not need to be run in a shell (By default the subprocess.Popen does not use any kind of a shell environment it just execs it).  Because of this we cant simply supply 'ps -U 0' to Popen.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a third party library, such as [PSI](http://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home):

> PSI is a Python package providing real-time access to processes and other miscellaneous system information such as architecture, boottime and filesystems. It has a pythonic API which is consistent accross all supported platforms but also exposes platform-specific details where desirable.

Comment: PSI was last updated in 2009, whereas psutil was updated this month (Nov 2015) - seems like psutil is a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to execute the command `ps` with appropriate options. By adding options you can modify which processes you see. Lot's of examples on subprocess on SO. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python) answers how to parse the output of `ps` for example:)

You can, as [one of the example answers showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python) also use the [PSI](http://www.psychofx.com/psi/) module to access system information (such as the process table in [this example](http://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home)).

Answer (score 0):

```
from psutil import process_iter
from termcolor import colored

names = []
ids = []

x = 0
z = 0
k = 0
for proc in process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    y = len(name)
    if y>x:
        x = y
    if y<x:
        k = y
    id = proc.pid
    names.insert(z, name)
    ids.insert(z, id)
    z += 1

print(colored("Process Name", 'yellow'), (x-k-5)*" ", colored("Process Id", 'magenta'))
for b in range(len(names)-1):
    z = x
    print(colored(names[b], 'cyan'),(x-len(names[b]))*" ",colored(ids[b], 'white'))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64906644/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This code is poorly written, needlessly complex, and unpythonic.  It is not a good example of how to achieve this.

Answer (score -3):

```
import os
lst = os.popen('sudo netstat -tulpn').read()
lst = lst.split('\n')
for i in range(2,len(lst)):
    print(lst[i])
```