# Looking at the task manager

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that is supposed to synchronize several different parts, 
including hardware. This is done by using a python script that communicates with
other programs.

I've found out that something I need for synchronization is for the main script
to be able to tell if another particular program is running, or if it stops.

I imagine it would look someting like:

```
#checking if a program runs

if is_running(program):
    statements

#Waiting for a program to stop

while is_running(program):
    pass
```

Does anyone know? I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't know what you are using, but there are a few questions answered already about this topic, for linux : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python

and windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: Python 2.7 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows) is pretty similar to your situation, and suggests using [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html) which will run on python 2.4 to 3.2 and Windows 7, or using the builtin [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) to get the list of proc.

If you care about making the code cross platform, you could also use [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#quick-links), which works on "Linux, Windows, OSX, FreeBSD and Sun Solaris, both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.4."