# How to find a process user name in python

Tags: python, wmi

I writing a script to automatically kill processes that have a specific `user name`. I'm using `wmi` library to find all the process and `os` to kill processes. I need a way to find the `user name` of the process so that I can kill it.

Here's a snippet

```
import os
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

for process in c.Win32_Process():
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)


def terminate(processName):
    os.system('taskkill /IM "' + processName + '" /F')
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe inside the os.system command? In Linux I'd say
`os.system('pkill ' + processName + '  -u  ' + userName)`

Comment: What I need is, the code to find the user name of a process, not the command to kill. I already have a function for killing

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978652/9267296). It's not WMI based, but it does what you want...

Comment: `process.GetOwner()` is what you want. It returns a tuple (Domain, ReturnValue, User). It's worth noting though that unless you're running with Administrator privileges it returns `(None, 2, None)` if the process is not yours.

Comment: Yeah just use `psutil`. Is there any reason why not?

Comment: `GetOwner` return codes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/getowner-method-in-class-win32-process#return-value

Comment: @GordonAitchJay GetOwner() gets the username for the pc not the process

Comment: psutil seems to be the way to go let me do some research on it

Comment: @Laspeed "GetOwner() gets the username for the pc not the process". What has lead you to believe that? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/getowner-method-in-class-win32-process) states: _The GetOwner WMI class method retrieves the user name and domain name under which the process is running._

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Yeah you're right I just went back to my task manager and scroll through and saw Admin in there along with other user name such as network service/local/system. What I actually wanna do is be find the network services and kill them. Unfortunately whenever I use GetOwner() the sole results I get are either `Admin` or `none`