# How to check if program is running by python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

Now I have a udp_server.py to run.

According to my less experience, I will do a python script in crontab as bellow.

```
import commands
output = commands.getoutput("ps aux | grep udp_server.py")
'''print output 
user      8695  0.0  0.3  50948 14196 pts/0    S    10:21   0:00 python udp_server.py
user      9486  0.0  0.0   4400   584 pts/0    S+   10:34   0:00 sh -c {  ps aux | grep 'udp_server.py'; } 2>&1
user      9488  0.0  0.0   9384   888 pts/0    R+   10:34   0:00 grep udp_server.py
'''
if 'python udp_server.py' in output:
    print "The server is active."
```

is this right?

Comment: What is "right" for you?  Does running `udp_server.py` print that kind of output?  Are you trying to run the `pgrep` command to check if the process is running already?  Is this being run within `udp_server.py` to see if it's already running from the cron job and as such would have to ignore itself in the list?

Comment: Also, you might want to check this question: [Process list on Linux via Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python)

Comment: sorry, I type error command.

Comment: Do you mean to `control a processes` ?

Comment: I just want to know the process whether it is existent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to type command line as like typing in unix console, it's right.

Suppose you will package the code in a file, maybe you will encounter a problem: it can't excute
command. It's because your account in linux hasn't enough authority, I suggest you do as the following:

```
sudo python command_file.py
```

By the way, if you really work in python2.6+, please notice the api, deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead.
So I suggest you replace it form `subprocess`.
Reference hypelink: [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html)