# Is it possible to run code when any browser is executed?

Tags: python, vb.net, batch-file, vbscript

I am new here & into programming.
Maybe my question sounds stupid - whether it may be very simple or not possible at all...
Anyway, it is possible to "sleep" until any browser is executed/active?
I don't mind whether it is vb, vbs, bat, python...
Thanks!

Comment: Your actual question is probably not stupid, but your current question is completely unclear. How and where are you executing your code? What permissions do you have on the system it is being executed on?

Comment: on Linux you could use `ps` to see running program.

Comment: Well I'm doing some experiments (admin account) & trying to figure this out so maybe I could use it on some projects if it is possible. Basicly I'd like to run a script/file or whatever commands are in the code that follows once I open chrome let's say. Like an autohotkey but an "event" or "processkey" in this case haha. I'm sure there's an elegant command to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python - psutil and PSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This vbscript checks every 15 minutes if an amount of programs is launched like ( chrome.exe,firefox.exe, iexplore.exe .... ) whether it finds nothing so it launch it.

```
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
     WScript.Echo "Instance already running"   
     WScript.Quit   
 Else   
     Do   
         Call Main(Array("%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe", "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"))  ', 
         Call Pause(15)   
     Loop   
 End If   

 Sub Main(colProcessPaths)   
     Dim ProcessPath   

     For Each ProcessPath In colProcessPaths   
         CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
     Next   
 End Sub   
  '*********************************************************************************************
 Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
     Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
     With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
         With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Commandline LIKE " &  CommandLineLike(ProcessName))   
             If .Count = 0 Then    
                 With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
                     WScript.Echo ProcessPath & vbCrLf & CommandLineLike(ProcessName) & vbCrLf & CommandLineLike(ProcessName) & vbCrLf 
                     .Run DblQuote(ProcessPath)   
                 End With   
             Else    
                 Exit Sub    
             End if   
         End With   
     End With   
 End Sub   
  '*********************************************************************************************
 Function AppPrevInstance()   
     With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
         With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
             AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
         End With   
     End With   
 End Function   
  '*********************************************************************************************
 Sub Pause(Minutes)    
     Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
 End Sub   
  '*********************************************************************************************
 Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
     Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
     StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
 End Function   
  '*********************************************************************************************
 Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
     ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
     CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
 End Function
 '*********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks!