# Which python script is running

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have several python Scripts running on a Raspi simultaneously. Depending on the Current time each might start running or stop running.
How can I find out which scripts are running using Python?

Comment: You can modify the scripts to save a log to somewhere...

Comment: you can [look here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=13475) for a way to check it with the pi and [check out this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python) for a way to check other programs with python.

Answer (score 10):

You can use command below in linux to get which script is runing.

```
ps -aef | grep python
```

And you will see which python scrip is running.