# Python,Shell: How to extract data and store in a iterable varible(specifically in list)?

Tags: python, shell, remote-server

I am working on my own project. In which these steps have to be performed:

1. Connect to remote server.
2. Get pid, process name, cpu usage, swap memory usage by each running process on remote server daily on some specific time(say at 4'0 clock).
3. I have to compare every day's result with previous day's result (e.g. day1-pid with day2 pid and day1 process name with day2 process name etc.)

So far I have done up to step-2. Now I want to know that how to extract the pid, process name, cpu usage, swap memory usage from remote server and store it in some iterable variable. So that I can compare it for checking memory spike?
Any other way apart from my idea will be appreciable. 
My code sample is like this:

```
import paramiko
import re
import psutil
class ShellHandler:
    def __init__(self, host, user, psw):
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=psw, port=22)

        channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell()
        self.stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
        self.stdout = channel.makefile('r')

    def __del__(self):
        self.ssh.close()

    @staticmethod
    def _print_exec_out(cmd, out_buf, err_buf, exit_status):
        print('command executed: {}'.format(cmd))
        print('STDOUT:')
        for line in out_buf:
            print(line, end="")
        print('end of STDOUT')
        print('STDERR:')
        for line in err_buf:
            print(line, end="")
        print('end of STDERR')
        print('finished with exit status: {}'.format(exit_status))
        print('------------------------------------')
        #print(psutil.pids())

        pass

    def execute(self, cmd):
        """

        :param cmd: the command to be executed on the remote computer
        :examples:  execute('ls')
                execute('finger')
                execute('cd folder_name')
        """
        cmd = cmd.strip('\n')
        self.stdin.write(cmd + '\n')
        finish = 'end of stdOUT buffer. finished with exit status'
        echo_cmd = 'echo {} $?'.format(finish)
        self.stdin.write(echo_cmd + '\n')
        shin = self.stdin
        self.stdin.flush()

        shout = []
        sherr = []
        exit_status = 0
        for line in self.stdout:
            if str(line).startswith(cmd) or str(line).startswith(echo_cmd):
                # up for now filled with shell junk from stdin
                shout = []
            elif str(line).startswith(finish):
                # our finish command ends with the exit status
                exit_status = int(str(line).rsplit(maxsplit=1)[1])
                if exit_status:
                    # stderr is combined with stdout.
                    # thus, swap sherr with shout in a case of failure.
                    sherr = shout
                    shout = []
                break
            else:
                # get rid of 'coloring and formatting' special characters
                shout.append(re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]').sub('', line).replace('\b', '').replace('\r', ''))

        # first and last lines of shout/sherr contain a prompt
        if shout and echo_cmd in shout[-1]:
            shout.pop()
        if shout and cmd in shout[0]:
            shout.pop(0)
        if sherr and echo_cmd in sherr[-1]:
            sherr.pop()
        if sherr and cmd in sherr[0]:
            sherr.pop(0)

        self._print_exec_out(cmd=cmd, out_buf=shout, err_buf=sherr, exit_status=exit_status)
        return shin, shout, sherr

obj=ShellHandler('Servername','username','password')
pID=[]
## I want this(pid, cmd, swap memory) to store in a varible which would be iterable.
pID=ShellHandler.execute(obj,"ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart,%mem,%cpu|awk '{print $1}'")
print(pID[0])##---------------------------------Problem not giving any output.
```

Comment: Your real question seems to be "ignoring all this code that I posted, how do I extract a few fields from a line of text"?

Comment: @tripleee, Yes but the data whatever we will extract it should be store in iterable variable because I wan to looping through it.

Comment: `list = [extracted_value_1, extracted_value_2, extracted_value_3]`. Maybe you want to look at various disk serialization approaches for storing today's results on disk so you can retrieve them tomorrow. `pickle` and `json` are popular, but there are many other ways.

Comment: Sir, so far I have got stuck in the 3rd line from bottom of my code. which I have commented. Pls give some suggestion on it specifically.

Comment: Anyway, why are you requesting multiple output fields from `ps` when you then discard all except the first with `|awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: Sir, I thought an approach that all the data(id, cmd, %mem and %cpu) , first I'll store in a iterable varible (in list format) one by one. So that I'll be able to iterate it in a loop to check for memory spike.  By "| awk'{print $1}'" I was testing whether it is working same as my thought or not. but when I tried to get zero'th index element it didn't give. Which is my real problem. Thanks.

Comment: Then why do you say you have handled item 2 on your list successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ShellHandler`'s `execute` method returns three items, the first of which is the *input* you sent to it.

You should probably call it directly like this, anyway:

```
obj = ShellHandler('Servername','username','password')
in, out, err = obj.execute("ps -eo pid,lstart,%mem,%cpu,cmd")
for line in out.split('\n'):
    pid, lstartwd, lstartmo, lstartdd, lstartm, lstartyy, mem, cpu, cmd = line.split(None, 8)
```

I moved `cmd` last because it might contain spaces.  The `lstart` value also contains multiple space-separated fields.  Here's what the output looks like in Debian:

```
19626 Tue Jan 15 15:03:57 2019  0.0  0.0 less filename
```

There are many questions about how to parse `ps` output in more detail; I'll refer you to them for figuring out how to handle the results from `split` exactly.

- [Splitting out the output of ps using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python)
- [Is there any way to get ps output programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559157/is-there-any-way-to-get-ps-output-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

`ps aux` command should have all the info you need (pid, process name, cpu, memory)

Comment: I have got the process related details but I have got stuck only in step-3. please help me out from step-3.

Comment: Well you can use grep or similar tools to extract the info you need from ps output, and store to a file for example which you could process further (eg compare against other values). I won't do your project for you. You have to show some work done already and you'll get assistance if you get stuck on some specific problem.

Comment: funckyjelly- I have uploaded my code snippet. Please have a look and help me.