# Linux / Bash using PS -f for specific PID returns in different format than PS -f, also queston about using Grep to parse this

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line, pid

I have a need, for a python script I'm creating, to first get just the PID of a process (based on its name) and then to get from that process, usings its PID, its time duration, which, from the printout below, would be "00:00:00"

```
root      5686     1  0 Sep23 ?        00:00:00 process-name
```

I am using this to get just the PID, by the process's name:

```
ps -ef |grep `whoami`| grep process-name | cut -c10-15
```

So, this works fine and I am assuming that the cut parameters (-c10-15) would work universally as the placement of the PID shouldn't change (I just got this from a snippet I found)

However, when I try to do something similar to get just the TIME value, such as this it returns it differently

```
ps -f 5686
```

returns:

```
root      5686     1  0 Sep23 ?        S      0:00 /path/to/process
```

So when I try a cut, as below, I don't think it would work properly as I'm not sure the spacing on this return is consistent and also its showing the time value differently than before (not the original "00:00:00" style of printout.

```
ps -f 5686 | cut -c40-47
```

I'm using this in my python script to record the PID of a specific process type (by name) so that I can later shut down that instance of the progra when needed. Any advice on what I can do to correct my approach is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -o option to control what data is output and in what order.

e.g.

```
$ ps -o pid,time,comm
  PID     TIME COMMAND
 3029 00:00:01 zsh
22046 00:00:00 ps
```

or

```
$ ps -o pid,time,comm --no-headers
 3029 00:00:01 zsh
22046 00:00:00 ps
```

This will make it easier to parse.  I would suggest parsing the output with python using `(pid, time, cmd) = result.split(2)`

Alternatively use the pgrep command to only list processes that match given criteria.

Comment: Thanks, I saw a post somewhere that mentioned something like this but couldn't figure it out from the ps -help output, I did locate the man page just now and see it, should have done that first

Comment: How can I get it to use ps -o for just a specific PID, I am trying  `ps -o 8783 pid,time,comm`  (trying with a PID I know exists) but its not working, thanks for the help in this

Comment: `ps -p 8783 -o pid,time,comm` should work; also try `ps -C command_name -o pid,time,comm`

Comment: well, do read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python, and checkout http://www.psychofx.com/psi/ and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
ps ux | awk '/$PROCESS_NAME/ && !/awk/ {print $2, $10}'
```

It should give you PID and TIME
(adapted from [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-10.html))

EDIT:
Version with `-ef`

```
ps -ef | awk '/$PROCESS_NAME/ && !/awk/ {print $2, $7}'
```

Comment: I'm using a Python call to do this so I want to first just get the PID and then cycle through each PID, just getting the time so that I can filter for the ones that are the newest (can handle this part in Python), I think I can adapt what you posted to do this, I'm just struggling with this as I don't know much bash / linux command line beyond the basics

Comment: No matter python or not, you can grab all the info and then analyse it in python; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682446/splitting-out-the-output-of-ps-using-python (and also the reasons not to use such approach)

Answer (score 0):

If you want consistent representation of the CPU time, read `/proc/<pid>/stat` and read the `utime` and `stime` fields.

Read `man 5 proc` to get the full layout of that file, but the easy bit is that you need the 14th and 15th values, and they're represented in "jiffies" (typically 100 per second), e.g.

```
% ps -e 2398
2398 ?        00:04:29 ypbind
```

00:04:29 is 269 seconds

```
% awk '{ print ($14 + $15) / 100 }' < /proc/2398/stat
269.26
```

or, in a Bash script without spawning a sub-process:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -a procstat /proc/pid/stat
let cpu=(procstat[13] + procstat[14]) / 100
```